# Trying to toggle html content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey so I have this HTML and i want to change the icon when its clicked

```
<span class="esconderInput" id="esconderInput">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></a>
</span>
```

and im trying to change it with jQuery with this code

```
$('#esconderInput').on('click',function(){
    if ( $( '#esconderInput' ).html() == '<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></a>' ) {
        $( this ).html( '<span class="esconderInput" id="esconderInput"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a></span>' );
        console.log( $( this ).html() );
    } else {
        $( this ).html( '<span class="esconderInput" id="esconderInput"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></a></span>' );
        console.log( $( this ).html() );
    }
});
```

it works on the first time i click, but not on the following, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: You're messing with the DOM just to replace a single css class? O.o -> [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass), [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass)

Comment: Can you try changing `$('#esconderInput').on('click',function(){` to `$(document).on('click', '#esconderInput', function(){`?

Comment: @j08691 That would make zero difference here, and they probably don't want to catch *all* clicks on the page, anyways.

Comment: The reason it works once is because the first time you change the html to something else that won't pass the if condition the next time.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, I know, the thing is that I am going to make other stuff on the function, not just that. So I'm just working on the logic right now. If it was only the css class i would use jQuery toggle class. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370544/using-if-else-with-onclick

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try code given below:

```
$('#esconderInput').on('click',function()
{
     if ($( '#esconderInput' ).html() == '<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></a>' ) 
     {
          $( this ).html( '<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>' );
          console.log( $( this ).html() );
     }
     else 
     {
          $( this ).html( '<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></a>' );
          console.log( $( this ).html() );
     }
} );
```

Comment: The `.html()` manipulation is part of the problem - it's making it harder for them to reason about what their code is doing in the first place.

Comment: It may "work" but it is encouraging the OP to write bad code.

Comment: I just helped Alejandro in modifying the code he has written!

Answer (score 4):

Try instead just changing the class of the icon's element.

```
$('#esconderInput').on('click', function () {
  var $icon = $(this).find('a i');
  if ($icon.hasClass('fa-minus-square')) {
    $icon.removeClass('fa-minus-square').addClass('fa-plus-square');
  } else {
    $icon.removeClass('fa-plus-square').addClass('fa-minus-square');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this is you wanted?
Use [ToggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to change classes between minus and plus.

```js
$('#esconderInput').on('click',function(){

   $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa fa-minus-square fa fa-plus-square");
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="esconderInput" id="esconderInput"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></a></span>
```

Comment: I know about toggle class, sorry I didn't explain that I was going to do other stuff int he functions, not just change the class. Thanks

Comment: You can do the other logic inside the function. i'm not understanding what is your other stuff?